# Complicated equations with one unknown

Tags: algebra-precalculus, numerical-methods

After checking a Physics problem, the answer is:

$$ y = \frac{(1+y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{2(y+\sqrt{3})^2} $$

The author then writes:

> Equation (12.4) can be solved numerically, and the result is y ≈ 0.1463. It can
> also be solved by iteration: evaluate the right side for some guessed initial
> y, then replace y with that calculated value. For this equation, the process
> converges rapidly to y ≈ 0.1463.

It is the first time I find this type of equation where there's only one unknown but seems too complex to arrange in a nice way. Do they have some names so I can research more about them?

Also, does this iterative process have some name as well? I'd like to know how it works. As choosing an initial value, solving and repeat seems kind of magical in this case.

Comment: There are many “iterative root finding methods” - search that, and you’ll get results. A very commonly used and simple one is Newton’s method

Comment: I'm aware of Newton's method. But can we say that in this case we are looking for a root?

Comment: Subtract $y$ from both sides - now you have a root! It is usually easy to convert an equation into one where one side equals zero

Comment: You can't solve it symbolically but with the substitution $y = x / \sqrt{3}$ it reduces to a "nicer" quintic $(x + 1) (x^5 + 15 x^4 + 54 x^3 + 90 x^2 + 9 x - 9) = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They use [fixed point iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration) and it works when the function is a contraction.

Let $g(y) = \frac{(1+y)^\frac32}{2(y+\sqrt3)^2}$, let's visualize its gradient function and check that $g$ is a contraction.

\begin{align}
g'(y) &= \frac12 \cdot \frac{\frac32(1+y)^\frac12 (y+\sqrt3)^2 - (1+y)^\frac322(y+\sqrt3)}{(y+\sqrt3)^4} \\
&= \frac{(1+y)^\frac12}{4(y+\sqrt3)^3}[3(y+\sqrt3)-4(1+y)] \\
&=\frac{\sqrt{1+y} \cdot (3\sqrt3-4-y)}{4(y+\sqrt3)^3}
\end{align}

We can see from its graph that the function $g'$ is bounded betweeen $0$ and $0.5$.

[image]

Hence $g$ is Lipschitz